# Add an object to a collection without knowing its generic type

Tags: c#, generics, collections, interface

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyInterface> myList = new List<MyInterface>();

        myList.Add(new MyClass<int>());

        foreach (MyInterface item in myList)
        {
            (MyClass)item).Foo(); // <---- Critical Line
        }
    }
}

interface MyInterface { }

class MyClass<T> : MyInterface
{
    public MyClass() { }
    public void Foo() { DoSomething(); }
}
```

I want to use the `Foo()` method of `MyClass` without knowing the excact (generic) Type of the object. Is there a way to call it anyway? I will know `T` when the code is compiled, so could I perhaps store it in a property that is implemeted via `InterfaceB`?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:** Sorry for not being clear; There are other classes that implement `MyInterface` and I am checking wether the type of item is ClassB, so I can't put `Foo()` into `MyInterface`.

Comment: It's not clear which interface is important to you here. Do you actually *need* `InterfaceA` and `ClassA` in order to demonstrate your problem, or are you really only interested in how to call `Foo`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet You're correct. I was just putting it the way I encountered the problem within my project.

Comment: Declare `Foo` in your interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key insight is that `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<SomethingElse>` are 100% unrelated types so you cannot treat them the same. Not even partially. It is as if you wrote `T1` and `T2` to the compiler.

So you have to create a common base class/interface or use `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to statically refer to `ClassB<T>` you will need to specify the generic parameter in your code.  You can't use the name `ClassB` because that will refer to a non-generic class named `ClassB`.

The other way to make this work is to add the information you need onto `InterfaceB` as it doesn't need a generic parameter

```
interface InterfaceB 
{
  InterfaceA FooUntyped();
}

...

foreach (InterfaceB item in bList) {
  aList.Add(item.FooUntyped());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interface MyInterface { }
interface MyFooInterface<T>
{
    List<T> Foo<T>();
}

class MyClass<T> : MyInterface, MyFooInterface<T>
{
    public MyClass() { }
    public List<T> Foo<T>() { DoSomething(); }
}

class MyClassB<T> : MyInfterface
{...}

...
        foreach (MyFooInterface item in myList.OfType<MyFooInterface>)
        {
            item.Foo();
        }
...
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! But do you also know a solution for the case that `Foo` returns a `List<T>`?

Answer (score -3):

You're not iterating over items of ClassB, but instead interfaceB which doesn't actually specify a Foo method.

Without checking however:

`var itemB = item as ClassB;
    if (itemB != null){
        itemB.Foo()
    }`

Comment: There's no such type as `ClassB` - there's only the *generic* type `ClassB<>`, and you can't check for an instance of that without supplying a type argument.